# session_write_close() failing just on request over https?

Tags: php, apache, session, https

**Following situation:**

- Apache2 Webserver
- PHP Version 5.5.38 (Module) (Upgrade not possible for the moment)

Test environment reachable over http://www.test-environment.com
Productive environment reachable over https://www.productive-environment.com
*(Fictional domains)*

Both systems are located on the same machine:

- /www/htdocs/myuser/test (Webroot of test environment, reachable over http)
- /www/htdocs/myuser/productive (Webroot of productive environment, forced HTTPS)

I got the following code and executed it on both systems, but they behave differently:

**session_write_close_test.php**

```php
<?php
session_start();

// Some logic here, but doesn't matter in the test case...

session_write_close();
set_time_limit(30);

$counter = 30;

while ($counter > 0) {
    sleep(1);
    $counter -= 1;
}
```

Calling the script on my test environment (http-only) over http://www.test-environment/session_write_close_test.php and calling http://www.test-environment.com within this 30 seconds in another tab, everything works fine. No blocking. session_write_close() seems to work.

Calling https://www.productive-environment.com/session_write_close_test.php and calling https://www.productive-environment.com within this 30 seconds in another tab: Nothing, until the test script ends. session_write_close() doesn't seem to work.

Any explanation for this behavior? Both systems use the same configuration. I already tried to change the session save path to prevent any file write permission issues, sadly with no effects.

Thanks in advance